# How to record each user's actions in C#?

Tags: c#, logging

I am trying to build a log that contains each action been done in my application like adding or removing data and so on . I googled and understood that i must use

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.currentuser()
```

this will tell me who is the current user but how can i record the actions done by this particular user ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'Action'? if they are applicative actions inside your applications than you need to log them manually. can you make the question less general?

Comment: yes i mean the actions they perform in my application . when they add remove , edit and so on ..... sorry for the mix up

Comment: Have a look at Postsharp. It will help you pre/post action logging.

Comment: I've added an answer about design patterns which can make you not need to write every 'log' action manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to log applicative actions done by the current user, you need to log them manually using libraries like `log4net` or on your own.

In order to make it easier for you and make your code shorter, you should consider design patterns like `Interceptor` (sort of `Decorator Factory` that can be implemented easily using `Castle Winsdor library` or `post-sharp` though the later is more unexpected) to decrease the  amount of times you need to log manually (by **Intercepting** the class doing your actions and make it log in every desired method call by `Attributing` the logged methods).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where you want to record those actions and what the actions are. You can write a SQL query that will save the data in a table, you cn use libraries like log4net. But remember if you want to record action per page/class, this need to be in every class.

Comment: just the actions like adding , editing and removing . Thanks

Comment: I noticed that the System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.currentuser() is a windows/desktop application class, and this present a challenge as you will only record actions that goes to your database/server and this can easily be done by adding a row to the table that will record the action done by, and possibly the time and computer name and you can write a report from the table(s), log4net is more helpful for webapplication

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your system performs some action initiated by the user, write something to a log file (or log table in a database, or whatever storage mechanism you prefer) that contains some information that identifies the user, for example the user name (which you get from `System.Windows.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name`).

Comment: so if my database contain for example name ,number .
i must create a new table in my database which contain the current user 
another field for the type of operation (add - edit -delete) and targeted value ( name - number ) and new value . is it correct ? and thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this problem as well. I was planning to add a seperate logging method to each custom action. eg: When a user deletes an object, a method activates to save the necessary info.

Though I might be making it more difficult than necessary.